# MarteEngine Tile Collision

Tags: java, slick

I need to add collision to my tile map using MarteEngine. MarteEngine is built of of slick2D. Here's my tile generation code:
Code:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException
   {
      for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            map[x][y] = AIR;
               air.draw(x * GameWorld.tilesize, y * GameWorld.tilesize);
         }
      }

   for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
         for (int y = 7; y < 8; y++) {
               map[x][y] = GRASS;
               grass.draw(x * tilesize, y * tilesize);
         }
      }

   for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
         for (int y = 8; y < 10; y++) {
            map[x][y] = DIRT;
               dirt.draw(x * tilesize, y * tilesize);
         }
      }

   for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
         for (int y = 10; y < 16; y++) {
            map[x][y] = STONE;
               stone.draw(x * tilesize, y * tilesize);   
         }
      }
      super.render(gc, game, g);


   }
```

And one of my tile classes (they're all the same, the image names are just different):
Code:

```
package MarteEngine;

import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

import it.randomtower.engine.entity.Entity;

public class Grass extends Entity {

   public static Image grass = null;

   public Grass(float x, float y) throws SlickException {
      super(x, y);

       grass = new Image("res/grass.png");

       setHitBox(0, 0, 50, 50);

       addType(SOLID);
   }

}
```

I tried to do it like this:
Code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
         for (int y = 7; y < 8; y++) {
               map[x][y] = GRASS;
               Grass.grass.draw(x * tilesize, y * tilesize);
         }
      }
```

But it gave me a NullPointerException. No idea why, everything looks initialized right? I would be very grateful for some help!

Comment: This should be an easy problem for you to solve by stepping through the code with [the debugger](http://byte56devtips.tumblr.com/post/20149822772/debuggers-breaking-bad-code). Honestly once you learn to use the debugger you will feel silly for having asked this question :)

Comment: @Byte56 Haha probably will but is it really that obvious? Can you at least give me a hint to which class its in?

Comment: What line is the it saying the null pointer is on?

Comment: Oh, I don't know where the problem is. I'm just saying *you* could figure it out in way less time than it took you to write the question. With the debugger it really will be that obvious.

Comment: @GameDev-er it says on line 58 of GameWorld which is my tile generation. Line 56 starts at: [code]Air.air.draw(x * GameWorld.tilesize, y * GameWorld.tilesize);
[/code]

Comment: Overall, I think this question is too localized for the site. (This is typically the case with questions that are about code errors).

Comment: I agree. This seems like it should be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted it looks like you never actually *call* the constructor for `Grass`, so `Grass.grass` is still `null`. It never gets a `new Image(...)` assigned to it. If you try to call a method on a `null` object, you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

What are the values of `AIR`, `GRASS`, `DIRT`, and `STONE`? Are they global?

**EDIT:**

Where in your code do you call the constructor for `Grass` (or `Air`, `Stone`, or `Dirt`)?

```
Grass theGrass = new Grass(0, 0);
```

Comment: Yes, they are in my GameWorld Class, and are just public static ints representing nothing pretty much. The code that is causing the error is actually Grass.grass.draw(). grass is set to null. But then I call on it later with grass = new Image(). Is this the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that the constructor for Grass is either 1) not called (leaving `Grass.grass` as `null`) or 2) called *after* the code that you posted above, so it hasn't initialized anything yet. I will update my answer with more information.

Comment: I call it in the Grass class with grass = new Image(res/grass.png); I realize this is not a constructor but all it is doing is setting an image. Then I call it with Air.air.draw(x * tilesize, y * tilesize);

Comment: I see that you instantiate the `Grass.grass` image in the `Grass` constructor, but that constructor never gets called, so the statement `grass = new Image(res/grass.png);` is never executed.

Comment: So how should I call it? I'm sorry, I'm really tired right now and its probably obvious but I just have no idea how to do it right now.

Comment: @opiop65 You need to invoke the `Grass` constructor at least once like the code near the end of my answer. Since you never call the constructor, the static data is never given a value other than `null`.